# LambdaExpression referencing private field

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

i'm planning to use global filters in EF CORE via HasQueryFilter, like this

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var filter = _tenantFilterProvider.GetExpression();

    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
        .HasQueryFilter(filter);
}
```

my lambda expression is provided by a class named TenantFilterProvider with a simple method that returns a LambdaExpression. This lambda expression references a private field that is declared in TenantFilterProvider

```cs
public class TenantFilterProvider
{
    private readonly CurrentTenant _currentTenant;

    public TenantFilterProvider(CurrentTenant currentTenant)
    {
        _currentTenant = currentTenant;
    }
    
    public LambdaExpression GetExpression()
    {
        Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> expression = entity => entity.TenantId == _currentTenant.TenantId;

        return expression;
    }
}
```

both TenantFilterProvider and CurrentTenant are registered in the builtin dependency injection from aspnetcore as scoped.

the lambda will be stored in a global variable inside the Ef Core model, so my fear is about the expression referencing a field (in this case _currentTenant).

will this create any type of memory issue? like a memory leak?

i uploaded the entire code to this repo if the provided code is not sufficient https://github.com/kewinbrand/EfCoreQueryFilter

Answer (score 0):

> both TenantFilterProvider and CurrentTenant are registered in the builtin dependency injection from aspnetcore as scoped.

This indicates that you expect a different instance of `CurrentTenant` to be injected with each request, right?

Since OnModelCreating is only called once, this expression will capture the CurrentTenant that is active for the request in which it is first called, and use that same tenant in every subsequent request, which I'm pretty sure is not the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: you're right, with my example the CurrenTenant.Id will be captured only when the model is creating. this is not the case if the lambda is declared inline, using the currentTenant as a field in the DbContext. i'm not sure why, like this HasQueryFilter(entity => entity.TenantId == _currentTenant.TenantId);